# How to deal with undetermined number of fields

Tags: database-design, data-modeling

The users inputs a initial date and a final date. It calculates and for example I'm using hardcoded 7, atm.

[image]

And my next field will be 7 days for the users to input data.

[image]

My question is: How do I save this data to a Database if I dont know how many days it will be? How can I create a table to store the data for each day and **IT NEEDS to be related to the type**. I wanted something on database like

EXAMPLE

```
 Individual
     Day1=20
     Day2=30
     ....
     Dayn=50
 Corporation
     ....
```

Comment: you mean, how to store number of days ?

Comment: @Ravi "store the data for each day" . Store the value the user enters on the textboxes

Comment: then, it is not SQL question is data modeling. You should do it yourself

Comment: And, in that case, you are dumping the question here without knowing your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem of having to keep adding n number of days. I would create an additional days table and join it to that table, then you can add as many days as you like.

clients

[image: clients]

days

[image: days]

Then you can join them like

```
SELECT `day`, `data` FROM `clients`  
INNER JOIN `days` 
ON `days`.`client_id`=`clients`.`id`  
WHERE `clients`.`type` = 'Individual'
```

to get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll want to come up with the data model that makes sense for how the data's going to be consumed.

Since the # of days is going to be dependent on user input, I'd probably go with a format that won't be affected by that (e.g. [Type, SystemDate, Quantity]). I'd then have to generate X amount of insert statements per type, where X is the days.

From there, using the business requirements I would decide what I should key the table on, should new entries for an existing Type/SystemDate be used to increment the existing values or replace them entirely, etc.

Comment: And this table would have a foreign key in my main table?